# My React Application is not running on the server

Tags: reactjs

Note: I am getting following error: when I give command `npm run server`,

> [nodemon] starting `babel-node server/index.js` sh: 1: babel-node:
>   Permission denied [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes
>   before starting...

Comment: I am already using babel-cli package and also configure webpack.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error message 'Permission denied' means that it can't run babel-node - did you install it with -g?

Comment: @Mikkel right now it is working thanks you sir.